# Hyper-V join virtual machine to a domain hosted in another virtual machine

Tags: windows, active-directory, server, hyper-v

I've been searching for this a lot, i have the following scenario:

A windows server 2012 R2 virtual machine in hyper-V with ADDS set up, hosting the domain "vm.local".

Another virtual machine with windows 8.1 pro in hyper-V that needs to join the vm.local domain.

How do i make the windows 8.1 vm to join the domain? It says "An active directory domain controller (AD DC) for the domain "vm.local" could not be contacted.

Additional info:
-the IP of the win server 2012 machine is 192.168.137.143
-the IP of the win 8.1 machine is 192.168.137.122
-the phisical machine hosting the hyper-v has AD DS set up with a "mainserver.local" domain, but i don't want the virtual machines to have anything to do with this. I just need one virtual machine joining the domain of the other.

Any tip will do.

Thank you.

*edit: i can ping one machine from another by their IP, but i cannot ping VMSERVER.vm.local

Answer (score 1):

You need to point your Windows 8.1 client to the vm.local DC for DNS. I would configure the DNS Server on the vm.local DC to forward unresolved requests to your mainserver.local DNS servers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I set my DNS server's IP address in the DNS setting and it is working. <3